# How to change the dimensions of the Facebook like button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-like

I'd like to change the dimensions of the Facebook like button.

I tried to change the padding of `<a class="connect_widget_like_button clearfix like_button_no_like">` using jQuery, but with no success.

Any ideas how it can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This content is served up in an Iframe. The **same origin policy** prevents you from accessing what's in there.

Answer (score 0):

Change the padding on the **a.connect_widget_like_button** class. That will change the button dimensions.

Comment: @sonicwizard I trid `$(document).ready(function() {
 $("a.connect_widget_like_button").css("padding", "50px 50px");
});`, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Ok, a couple ideas... First of all, I wonder if the Like button is not loaded yet (at document.ready). Try putting a delay in... setTimeout for 20 seconds or something just to test... and THEN change the padding. Second, try putting a.connect_widget_like_button in your CSS with padding settings and see if that works.

Comment: Also, is the Like button loading in an iframe? You might not have access to it?? I don't know, let me do a bit more research...

Comment: Well, yeah, it's an iframe, there is no other option. As for as I understand, CSS can't apply on an iframe. Also, setting a timeout doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to do this, per Facebook's usage guidelines. The only thing you can do is change the dimensions of the overall Like section. See http://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php

Comment: 'While you may scale the size to suit your needs, you may not modify the Like Button in any other way (such as by changing the design).', isn't it what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try targeting the iframe with CSS and scale it by using CSS3. Something like this:

```
#fbiframe
{
transform: scale(1.5);
-ms-transform: scale(1.5); 
-webkit-transform: scale(1.5); 
-o-transform: scale(1.5); 
-moz-transform: scale(1.5); 
transform-origin: top left;
-ms-transform-origin: top left;
-webkit-transform-origin: top left;
-moz-transform-origin: top left;
-webkit-transform-origin: top left;
}
```

Here's an example http://www.tinydesign.co.uk/like/